# Ajuda com consulta SQL

Tags: mysql, query, select

Tenho 3 tabelas:

empresa:

```
id integer
nome string
```

categoria:

```
id integer
idEmpresa integer
nome string
```

tag:

```
id integer
idEmpresa integer
nome string
```

Eu estou consultando da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT
distinct(e.nome),
e.id,
e.logo
FROM empresas e,
tags t
where (e.nome like '%texto%'
or e.subcategoria like '%texto%'
or t.tag like '%texto%')
and t.idEmpresa = e.id
and e.logo is not null
order by rand()
```

Ele consulta corretamente, mas só se existir alguma tag cadastrada vinculada à empresa, caso não exista, ele ignora o cadastro.

Como fazer pra buscar uma empresa tanto pelo nome, categoria ou tag, independente de ter uma tag cadastrara?

Comment: Essa forma de select 'select from tabela1, tabela2 ...' Faz um INNER Join, você precisa de um left join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a clausula **LEFT JOIN**, pois ele irá pegar todos os cadastros independentes de tag ou não. Além disso, usando **JOIN** não é mais necessário fazer projeção entre as tabelas filtrando pelo **WHILE**, ou seja, `... and t.idEmpresa = e.id ...` não é mais necessário.

```
SELECT distinct(e.nome), e.id, e.logo
FROM empresas e
LEFT JOIN tags t ON  e.id = t.idEmpresa
where (e.nome like '%texto%'
or e.subcategoria like '%texto%'
or t.tag like '%texto%')
and e.logo is not null
order by rand()
```

A seguir outros tipos de União, que podem te ajudar a resolver outros problemas.

[image: Outros tipos de JOIN]

Comment: opa, continua do mesmo jeito. eu digito o nome de uma empresa que não tem tags cadastradas e ela não é listada

Comment: Tente executar sem o Where e o Order by, vê se todos os cadastros são exibidos. Se sim o problema está na clausula WHERE

Comment: sim, o erro era em `and t.idEmpresa = e.id`, pois já tinha o mesmo no join. valleu